# Rails / Dragonfly - My mp4 aren't displayed on ipad

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, ipad, video

I'm running a cms which provides pictures, texts and videos. On my mac everything is fine in every browser. On my iPad everything is running well except for the videos. On my iPad the video play sign is shown crossed and the videos doesn't play.

Here's an example:
http://production.oleast.de/media/W1siZiIsIml0ZW0tMS9sYW5ndWFnZS0xL3ZpZGVvLTk4ODc3NC0xNTY5NjE3MTYubXA0Il1d/156961716.mp4?sha=b9d8a99b57da6c96

When I check my page considering the HTTP Response Header I get the following:

> HTTP Response Header
>   Name    Value   Delim
>   Status: HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date:   Mon, 21 Sep 2015 19:31:05 GMT
>   Status: 200 OK
>   Content-Type:   video/mp4
>   Content-Length: 1916321 
>   Content-Disposition:    filename="156961716.mp4"
>   Cache-Control:  public, max-age=31536000
>   ETag:   "e9173ff260b8b14eac702792d09e4fd570937c1e"
>   X-Request-Id:   034d4136-8964-4540-bc35-bda642ff4b57
>   X-Runtime:  0.003765
>   X-Content-Digest:   073728ecfa943fd5dbe7a847a905a4f59fd1d1ae
>   Age:    807 
>   X-Rack-Cache:   fresh
>   X-Powered-By:   PleskLin
>   Connection: close

The same video, provided outside my rails app, is running.

I would be very thankful if anyone could help me out or give me a hint / solution to my problem.

Comment: Check the MOOV atom moved to the beginning in front of data itself

Comment: Did you find any solution here, I am having similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the issue with Rails.
It's restrictions from iOS itself.

According to [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html):

> In Safari on iOS (for all devices, including iPad), where the user may be on a cellular network and be charged per data unit, preload and autoplay are disabled. No data is loaded until the user initiates it... On the desktop or iPad, you must either include the controls attribute or provide playback controls using JavaScript. It is especially important to provide user controls on iPad because autoplay is disabled to prevent unsolicited cellular download.

So you should probably try to remove `autoplay` and adding `controls` attribute to your `<video>` tag.

Comment: Thanks, but in my production view of the cms controls are enabled and autoplay is disabled. The result is the same. I read about some HTTP Header Response issues but cannot figure out what's wrong.

Comment: @Manuel in the link you provided autoplay is enabled `<video controls="" autoplay="" name="media">`

Comment: Yes. But here it isn't: http://production.oleast.de/api/v1/items/1/languages/1/view

Comment: You still using "autobuffer" attribute, try removing it too.

Comment: removed without any changes.